# Arrays in Matlab/Python, indexing errors

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

I have been converting some Matlab code into Python. I have been debugging this program for a while and I am wondering if I am correct in the way I am thinking about the arrays in Matlab.

I have this code in Matlab (edited to add missing variables and executions):

```matlab
pdf_pars = pdf_pars(1)*ones(1,p);
weights = 1;

% determine  the size of each lenght
mode_length = round(weights*samp_size);

% correct for rounding erros
mode_length(no_modes) = mode_length(no_modes) + samp_size - sum(mode_length) ;

for i=1:no_modes
    x = [x dirichlet(pdf_pars(i,:),mode_length(i))']; 
end
```

When you read the first line, it seemed to me like `mode_length` was an integer (or perhaps a double). However the next line starts indexing. I know that in Python, this treatment of `mode_length` will cause an error.

Am I interpreting this Matlab code correctly? And how can I work around this as I continue moving code into Python?

Comment: What exactly are `weights`,  `samp_size`,  and `no_modes`?

Comment: Judging by the variable names, `weights` is a vector, and `samp_size` is a scalar.

Comment: @rahlf23, the code is from an open source paper. samp_size is one of the required inputs and it is described as the "number of spectral vectors to be generated". So I believe it is a scalar. Weights is also a scalar.

Comment: If `weights` and `samp_size` are both scalars (which I'm skeptical is the case), then `mode_length` will be a scalar. The reason for my skepticism is because you then try to index `mode_length` in the following line...

Comment: The important value is really `no_modes` because this is the index you are trying to query

Comment: @rahlf23 that makes perfect sense. I am confused myself with the code. I will add the code that applies to the tester program I am making and provide values. A colleague of mine who just looked over the code suggested that in my particular testing case, weights and samp_size are both scalars.

Comment: This is still not a reproducible example, sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

[`round(X)`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) in Matlab rounds *each element* of `X`. If you feed it a vector, it returns a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `weights`, `samp_size`, and `no_modes` are, this is somewhat speculative.

With that being said, `round()` in MATLAB will retain the size that is passed as an input. Therefore, if you pass a double, then it will round the double and return a double. Likewise, if you pass a vector, then MATLAB will perform the rounding element-wise and return a vector.

So assuming that `weights` is a vector and `samp_size` is a scalar, then you are applying `round()` to each element of the resulting vector from `weights*samp_size`, thus `mode_length` will be a vector.

Then it looks like you are modifying the element in `mode_length` that corresponds to index `no_modes`, and simply adding `samp_size` and subtracting `sum(mode_length)`, both of which are scalar values.

Something to note if you are not aware: MATLAB indexing begins at `1`, whereas Python indexing begins at `0`.

Comment: I clarified what some of the variables were. Weights and samp_size are both scalars. At least in the call that I make that results in these errors, weights has a value of 1.